# Display name & picture knowing ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api, profile, image

I was looking to find an answer to my question, but so far I got this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/the_user_id?fields=name,picture`

I need to be able to display/print first,last name and picture of a set list of users for which I know their ID. What code is required to get this data and then to publish it on a php/html page? Of course, this will means that if I want to show 10 users, I will input 10 different IDs (read smtg about an array list?). Notice that I DO NOT require for this to work for the current user.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use file_get_contents ( https://www.php.net/file_get_contents ) or curl in php and issue a request to the url such as follows:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=id1,id2,id3&fields=name,picture
```

(replacing id1,id2 with your ids)

this will then return you a json object. You then need to decode ( https://www.php.net/json_decode ) and loop through this and access the information

this should get you started

```
// people array uses the users id as the key and the dessert as the value. The id is then used in the query to facebook to select the corresponding value from this array
$people = array("id1"=>"favourite "dessert", "id2"=>"favourite dessert", "id3"=>"apple pie");

 $json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=id1,id2,id3&fields=id,name,picture');
 $json = json_decode($json);
foreach($json as $key=>$person){
   echo '<p><img src="'.$person->picture.'" alt="'.$person->name.'" />';
   echo $person->name.'\'s favourite dessert is '.$people[$person->id'];
   echo '</p>';
}
```

I've batched the requests here, alternatively you could perform 10 separate queries for each user, but that would be a bit pointless and inefficient

Comment: Tommy, this work perfectly. Now, what if I need to have something like this:

(pic) John Smith's favorite dessert is apple pie

(pic) Jane Doe's favorite dessert is chocolate cake
   

As you see, a repetitive text ('s favorite dessert is ) and a unique one (dessert's name) will need to be added. How to achieve this? I was thinking that maybe either:

- Making single queries, adding the extra text (slowest)
- Adding some coding that make us able to attach the dessert's name to each ID like: 8675309&apple pie,1234567&chocolate cake,etc

Once again, thanks for your time explaining/solving this.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you how you could achieve this. I'm assuming you already have the favourite dessert and the id of the user.Please note I edited the file_get_contents call to include returning the id as well

Comment: Hey Tommy, it seems that due to new changes by Facebook, the code is giving me an error: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/website/public_html/directory/fblike_1.php on line 50 which is: ----echo '<p><img src="'.$person->picture.'" alt="'.$person->name.'" />';-----  any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Hi I think $person->picture now needs to be $person->picture->data->url

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with an FQL query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, pic, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN 
  (Known_ID_1, Known_ID_2, ... Known_ID_n)
```

The easiest, if you're using PHP is to install the [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php), though you can also make a call directly to `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=URL_ENCODED_QUERY`